# comparing status code of the response

Tags: f#

I'm getting an error that says result of this expression is implicitly ignored. Consider using ignore to discard this value explicitly... not understanding what's wrong in here?

```
let makeRequest url =  

    let request = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
    request.Method <- "POST"
    request.ContentType <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Accept <- "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    request.ContentLength <- (int64)data.Length

    use requestStream = request.GetRequestStream() 
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, (data.Length))
    requestStream.Flush()
    requestStream.Close()
    let response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse

    if response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK then // error here
        "success"
    else 
        "fail"
```

calling

```
makeRequest "http://example.co"
```

Comment: can someone explain what's wrong with the question?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context - what is around the code in the question? What is the code supposed to be doing? What do you want to do with the string that the branch returns?

Comment: i was trying to be brief and focused on the problem, the function returns success or false if status code is not OK

Comment: If makeRequest is meant to be a function, it should have at least 1 parameter

Comment: Are you getting the error on the line with `makeRequest "http://example.co"` ? Is this in a script file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function makeRequest returns a string and your call to

`makeRequest "http://example.co"`

does nothing with the return value. If you change your call to

`makeRequest "http://example.co" |> ignore`

then the return value is ignored.